# Howto Move Swatches in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, swatches

Im not able to figure out the block name of swatches or how to move the swatches block inside product listing. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Stian

Comment: how to move the swatches block inside product listing ? what do mean by that you want swatches with product on product listing ?

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar Move it around i mean, it is located within <div class="product details product-item-details">, however i need to move it into <div class="product-image"> when list view is active